# what does double star followed by variable name mean in python?

Tags: python, zsi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does ** (double star) and * (star) do for python parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters)

I am reading some code that been generated by ZSI for python. There is a line like this

`def verifyVehicle(self, request, **kw):
    ....`

I want to know what does this **kw neams. Is this neam a dictionary type? Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It refers to all keyword arguments passed to the function that aren't in the method definition.  For example:

```
>>> def foo(arg, **kwargs):
...     print kwargs
... 
>>> foo('a', b="2", c="3", bar="bar")
{'c': '3', 'b': '2', 'bar': 'bar'}
```

It is similar to just using one asterisk, which refers to all non-keyword arguments:

```
>>> def bar(arg, *args):
...     print args
... 
>>> bar(1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b')
(2, 3, 'a', 'b')
```

You can combine these(and people often do)

```
>>> def foobar(*args, **kwargs):
...     print args
...     print kwargs
... 
>>> foobar(1, 2, a='3', spam='eggs')
(1, 2)
{'a': '3', 'spam': 'eggs'}
```

Comment: That explains everything! Thanks